# Looking for design pattern to create multiple models/collections out of single JSON responses

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, model

I have a Backbone application where the JSON I get from the server isn't exactly 1 on 1 with how I want my models to look. I use custom parse functions for my models, ex:

```
parse: function(response) {
   var content = {};
   content.id = response.mediaId;
   content.image = response.image.url;
   return content;
}
```

This works. But, in some cases I have an API call where I get lots of information at once, for instance, information about an image with its `user` and `comments`:

```
{
    "mediaId": "1",
    "image": {
        "title": "myImage",
        "url": "http://image.com/234.jpg"
    },
    "user": {
        "username": "John"
    },
    "comments": [
        {
            "title": "Nice pic!"
        },
        {
            "title": "Great stuff."
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I go about creating a new User model and a Comments collection from here? This is an option:

```
parse: function(response) {
   var content = {};
   content.id = response.mediaId;
   content.image = response.image.url;
   content.user = new User(response.user);
   content.comments = new Comments(response.comments);
   return content;
}
```

The trouble here is, by creating a `new User` or `new Comments` with raw JSON as input, Backbone will just add the JSON properties as attributes. Instead, I'd like to have an intermediate `parse`-like method to gain control over the objects' structure. The following is an option:

```
parse: function(response) {
    // ...
    content.user = new User({
        username: response.user.username
    });
    // ...
}
```

...but that's not very DRY-proof.

So, my question is: what would be a nice pattern to create several models/collections out of 1 JSON response, with control over the models/collections attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the nicest way possible, but this is how I do it:

```
content.user = new User(User.prototype.parse(response.user));
```

The only problem is that the `this` context in `User.parse` will be wrong. If you don't have any specific code in the `User` constructor, you can also do:

```
content.user = new User();
content.user.set(user.parse(response.user));
```

I also noticed an interesting note in the Backbone version 0.9.9 change log:

> The parse function is now always run if defined, for both collections and models — not only after an Ajax call.

And looking at the source code of `Model` and `Collection` constructor, they do it like so:

```
if (options && options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs);
```

Maybe upgrading to 0.9.9 will give you what you need? If upgrade is not an option, you can of course implement the same in your own constructor.

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading to 0.9.9 broke my code (haven't figured out how, but always running `parse` probably has something to do with it :) but your other solution is perfectly OK